# ¿Como puedo añadir recursos a un instalador de c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Lo que pasa que quiero hacer un instalador de un trabajo para el colegio, en alguna parte del código hago referencia a una dirección de un archivo dentro de mi ordenador .mp3, pero mi duda es como puedo añadir eso al instalador y de esta forma no tener problema al momento de reproducir dicho sonido (se supone que la persona que instale mi programa no tendrá la mismas dirección de archivos que yo).Dejo un ejemplo para quedar un poco mas claro:

```
   SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav");
   simpleSound.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

deberás añadir el archivo a la carpeta resources de la aplicación y si realizas el instalador mediante la opción publicar comprobar luego que se añaden en el instalador desde:

```
 Explorador de soluciones>botón derecho propiedades>publicación>Archivos de aplicación
```

Si utilizas otro instalador mas avanzado como windows installer o Installshield deberás revisar como añadirlo en cada caso